# Как правильно хранить деньги php

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, типизация

Пытался разобраться в вопросе как правильно хранить деньги в php.
Судя по обсуждению этой темы - в других ЯП во флоатах (и прочих типас с плавающей точкой) их хранить нельзя из-за погрешности. [Тут](https://qna.habr.com/q/23947) более-менее что-то стало понятно, но так и не нашел какой-то однозначный ответ.
Тот же вопрос касается и хранения их в базе данных.

Пересмотренная литература:
[https://overcoder.net/q/54116/php-mysql-лучшие-практики-операций-с-деньгами-хранения](https://overcoder.net/q/54116/php-mysql-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.float.php
https://qna.habr.com/q/23947

Может у кого есть примеры с практики, или личный опыт?

Comment: php не хранит деньги, если речь за бд, то decimal говорят самый подходящий вариант.

Comment: к примеру я получаю с бд инфу о зарплате сотрудника, создаю для нее переменную, какого типа я ее делаю? Насчет бд - понял, попробую.

Comment: Если будет decimal, то на php это будет float, ещё кстати вариант хранить в копейках, тогда не прогадаешь никогда, сам обычно этим способом пользуюсь.

Comment: За копейки - понял, сталкивался с этим решением ранее, там просто же суть в том что мы умножаем\делим на 100, и все, верно? Просто думал есть решение поизящнее. Но вот часть вашего комментария насчет float - ну не знаю, не уверен что это правильно...

Comment: Умножаем/делим это минус, но зато нет проблем с float на php.